# swt or jface code to create a text editor and canvas

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

*i am looking for text editor and canvas part in eclipse rcp application.  can any one recommend the code for text editor and canvas using jface or swt *

i know i can use `Canvas canvas=new Canvas(parent, style)`

to create canvas but i need full code.

*i have checked with vogella examples http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php and http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets.php but i didn't meet the correct specifications.*

Comment: What do you mean, you didn't meet the correct specifications? Here is a link that might help: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html

Answer (score 1):

[SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) contains demo code for many different use cases.

In your case, you should look at "[paint a circle in a canvas](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet245.java)".

The section "StyledText" contains snippets how to work with the SWT component of the same name. The [SWT standalone examples](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php) have a [simple styled text editor example](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/samples/org.eclipse.swt.examples/doc-html/swt_texteditor_ex.html).

Answer (score 0):

The JFace `org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer` class provides a basic text editor.

If you are using full Eclipse then `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` provides a more elaborate editor framework.